# Getting the package.json version inside yml for gitlab releases

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci.yml

I am working on a small component library and I am writing a yml file to release a package every time I push to the master or make a merge request. The script works just fine but what I am trying to do is getting the version from inside package.json and just print it for now (later I will use it in a different way). Here is the release job inside yml file:

```
release-job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH 
  script:
    - echo "running release-job for $TAG"
    - VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
  release: 
  tag_name: 'v0.$CI_PIPELINE_IID' # The version is incremented per pipeline.
  description: 'This is the new version: v0.$CI_PIPELINE_IID and package.json = $VERSION'
  ref: '$CI_COMMIT_SHA' # The tag is created from the pipeline SHA.
  tags:
    - SharedRunner
```

So the problem now is that when I set the image to the value above, the job runs but says that node is not found while changing it to node:latest fixes the issue but says that release-cli is not found. How can I get them both to work so I can fetch the package version and still run the release-cli?

Thanks in advance,
Saif.

Answer (score 2):

There's two (+1) possibilities:

A. Add another stage with node image to retrieve the version and save it as an env in a file. Mark the file as an artifact and make sure to set the release-job `needs` property for the versioning-job.

```yaml
script:
  - NPM_PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version") # get version
  - echo "NPM_PACKAGE_VERSION=NPM_PACKAGE_VERSION" >> variables.env # save in env
artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env # save as artifact
<...>
# then in your other job add the following to import the env
  needs:
    - job: <get-version-job-name> 
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - echo "$NPM_PACKAGE_VERSION" # should print your version e.g. 1.0.0
```

B. Use a shell script to retrieve the version in the release-cli image.

```
script:
    - export PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F= "{ print $2 }" | sed 's/[version:,\",]//g' | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
    - echo $PACKAGE_VERSION # should print your version e.g. 1.0.0
```

C. Do a combination of both

If you need the version in more than one job, I suggest solution A because you can set it as the first job to be executed and then import the artifacts in following jobs. How you extract the version (node or some other image) stays up to you.